# How to use an input to terminate a program in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

What I am trying to accomplish with this program is for a user to enter as many numbers as they would like into a vecor. After the user is finished I would like the user to enter the word "no". After the user inputs the word "no" the size of the vector, max vaule, min vaule and mean value will be calculated. My problem is I currently have my program set up to were if a user enters the number "0" the program will then terminate. The issue with this is that number input gets calculated in the vector size and minimum vaule calculation. Is there anyway where a user can enter the string vaule "no" and terminate the program instead entering the number zero?

Thanks !

```
enter code here

#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::vector<double> numbers;
    std::vector<double>::iterator it;

    double number;
    cout<<"Hello! Enter as many numbers as you would like! \n When you are finished enter 0"<<endl;

    while (cin>>number){

        numbers.push_back(number);{

            while(number==0){
                for (it=numbers.begin(); it !=numbers.end(); it++)
                cout << *it<< " ";
                cout << endl;

                cout<< "The total size of the Numbers vector is: "<<numbers.size();

                double max = *max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
                cout << "\nMax Value: "<<max<<endl;

                double min = *min_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
                cout << "Min Value: "<<min<<endl;

                double mean = accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0) / numbers.size();
                cout <<"Mean Value: "<<mean<<endl;

                return 0;
            }

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

}
        enter code here

Comment: Yes, ONLY use your `while(cin>>number)` loop to get input. Since `number` is a double, entering anything that can't be parsed as double (including "no", "yes", "maybe", etc) will cause the input to fail, the condition to return false, and the input to stop.

After an input operation fails on a stream (like `cin`), it's good practice to both `clear()` and `ignore()` on it to clear any further erroneous input. (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Move all of your output to OUTSIDE (after) the input loop.

Comment: `std::string s; while (cin >> s) { if (s == "no") break; ...`

Comment: @JohnFilleau Thanks for the response! That article helped a lot. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Eljay Appreciate the response! I was able to implement this in my source code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read each line as a `std::string` and check if it's `no`. If it's not, convert it to a `double` (using `std::stod` for example) and save it.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> numbers;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        if(line == "no") break;
        try {
            numbers.push_back(std::stod(line));
        } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
            // converting to double failed
            std::cout << ex.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
    // do your calculations
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response! This was extremely useful. I was able to implement it in my source code. Thanks!

Comment: Done, appreciate the help !